# Is it okay to prepare SQL statement once for multiple request?

Tags: sql, go, prepared-statement

I have some SQL queries that do not change on every request (only it's parameter). So, instead of doing this for each request:

```
func HandleRequest() {
    rows, err := db.Query(sqlQuery, params...)
    // do something with data
}
```

Is it okay if for each reqest I do this instead:

```
// together with server initialization
stmt, err := db.Prepare(sqlQuery)

func HandleRequest() {
    rows, err := stmt.Query(params...)
    // do something with data
}
```

Comment: In practice, no, because you cannot use statements concurrently. You would have to serialize your requests, which is almost certainly not acceptable.

Comment: @Peter huh? The docs on `Prepare` state *"Multiple queries or executions may be run concurrently from the returned statement."*, am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @mkopriva, "When the Stmt needs to execute on a new underlying connection, it will prepare itself on the new connection automatically." I don't recall this happening when I last tried something similar. I saw the same symptoms that happen when a transaction is used concurrently. Perhaps that changed since then or it was a bug in the database driver. Good to know that this is supposed to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the documentation of [`DB.Prepare()`](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB.Prepare) states:

> Multiple queries or executions may be run concurrently from the returned statement.

It is safe for concurrent use, although the *intended* use for prepared statements is not to share them between multiple requests. The main reason is that a prepared statement (may) allocate resources in the DB server itself, and it's not freed until you call the `Close()` method of the returned statement. So I'd advise against it.

The typical use case is if you have to run the same statement multiple times with different parameters, such as the example in the documentation:

```
projects := []struct {
    mascot  string
    release int
}{
    {"tux", 1991},
    {"duke", 1996},
    {"gopher", 2009},
    {"moby dock", 2013},
}

stmt, err := db.Prepare("INSERT INTO projects(id, mascot, release, category) VALUES( ?, ?, ?, ? )")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
defer stmt.Close() // Prepared statements take up server resources and should be closed after use.

for id, project := range projects {
    if _, err := stmt.Exec(id+1, project.mascot, project.release, "open source"); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```