# Can't create more than max_prepared_stmt_count statements

Tags: mysql, go

I am encountering the following MySQL error from within my long-running Go application:
`Can't create more than max_prepared_stmt_count statements (current value: 16382)`

In my `main.go` file I create a struct which has a couple of `sql.Stmt` fields. By doing so I intend to reuse these prepared statements.

The code looks somewhat like this, in `factory.go`:

```
func NewFactory(db *sql.DB) (*Factory, error) {
    insertStmt, err := db.Prepare("INSERT INTO `table` (`a`, `b`, `c`) VALUES   (?,?,?);")

    // Same for deleteStmt

    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    f := &Factory{
        insertStmt: insertStmt,
        deleteStmt: deleteStmt,
    }

    return f, nil
}
```

And in my `main.go`:

```
    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "...")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    db.SetConnMaxLifetime(time.Minute)

    factory, err := NewFactory(db)

    // start a web server and handle those calls (basically an endless loop until the app is stopped)
```

**Note**: I do not call `insertStmt.Close()` because I want to reuse this prepared statement.

I have read http://go-database-sql.org/prepared.html which says that a prepared statement is bound to a single database connection. I know that setting `db.SetConnMaxLifetime(time.Minute)` will close the connection after a minute of idling, but this is done to prevent errors where the server closed the connection (MySQL `wait_timeout` parameter) but the client still thinks the connection is alive.

Can anyone explain what is happening and how I can prevent a buildup of prepared statements?

Comment: It looks you are misusing prepared statements. They keep resources allocated on the server side (in the DB server), so you should close them as soon as you don't need them. See [Is it okay to prepare SQL statement once for multiple request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58064081/is-it-okay-to-prepare-sql-statement-once-for-multiple-request/58064554#58064554)

Comment: Also, your quoted code would not cause the given error because what's shown only prepares 2 statements for the lifetime of the application. So there is somewhere else that is repeatedly creating prepared statements and not closing them.